# Log4j define length for combined pattern

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Is it possible to define an overall length for in the layout pattern for the combination of two or more conversion characters?

Right now I use

```
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern>[%-5level] | {%c{1}::%M (line %4L)} | %msg%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

But I want to define the overall length (width) of the complete expression

```
 {%c{1}::%M (line %4L)}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible with patterns according to [PatternLayout manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)

You can test patterns here: [online tester](http://log4jtester.com/)